# How can I get the post data from formdata

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am confusing how to get the data from ajax formdata. I only used get request until now. And I have never used formdata before. So, I don't know how can I handle the data.

My client script is the following.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('filename', image_file_name);
formData.append('image', image_file);

$.ajax({
    url: HOST_NAME + "user/api/file_uploader/",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 10000,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
.done(function (data) {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("failed");
})
```

And my server side code is the following.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    outputLogFile("Upload Function is called...")
    req_file_name = request.POST.form['filename']
    req_image = request.POST.form['image']
```

I want to get the filename into req_file_name and get the image into req_image. But I have no idea what I should do to achieve this.

Please give an advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are accessed via `request.FILES` rather than `request.POST` so you should use:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    req_image = request.FILES["image"]
    req_file_name = request.data["filename"]
```

When I am creating an image upload using this, I normally add this to my APIView:

```
class ExampleImageUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser, )
```

Do not forget to import them:

```
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser
```

Also you don't need `dataType: 'json',` so I'd just remove it.

Comment: Thank you for advices. I believe your advice will help me to solve my problem. But now, I got the error. 
req_file_name = request.POST['filename']
TypeError: 'QueryDict' object is not callable

I don't make sense what code cause this error. Please give me an advice.

Comment: @KazzzStudio are you sure you're using the [] brackets like my post says. The error suggests you are using () brackets instead

Comment: Thank you for reply. I certainly use []. 'req_file_name = request.POST['filename']' this message is copied from my uwsgi.log. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @KazzzStudio you may have to use `request.data` instead of `request.POST`, now that I think about it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I can fix it. Now I have another error. django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'image'". Maybe I am wrong on my client code. Anyway your advice help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: I believe that error is because no image was uploaded

Comment: I understand what you mean. I will try to fix it. Thanks.